# Which is better to stay in shared house or university accommodation?

Tags: masters, university

I will be a postgraduate student from this Oct in UK and looking for accommodation.
I would like to know pros and cons of shared house and accommodation provided by the University.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is very much University/location specific. Generally, though, living outside of university accommodation is significantly cheaper and, often, more spacious. On the other hand, if you are international, you likely won't have a landlord reference so uni flats may be your only option.

Comment: The university is University of Reading

Comment: Yep, can't speak for Reading. Perhaps someone else can.

Comment: Done both (at a different location), perhaps start in Uni Acc then get some friends and share...

Comment: This will differ greatly from place to place. As one data point, where I went to grad school: the university's grad student housing was far from the main part of campus and from all the restaurants and shops. The advantages were that it was near hiking trails, and that there was a community center that organized social activities. It seemed to be popular with international students and with students who had kids.

Comment: thank you guys for the comments! I will re-think about what I need and do research again.

Comment: Uni accommodation will be full of undergrads... don't put yourself through that! Find a flatshare with other postgrads, there are loads of Facebook groups around for that sort of thing.

Comment: Thank you astronat! I see, I will check facebook group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The University of Reading publishes cost of living information on its website

https://studyabroad.reading.ac.uk/incoming/costs/

The costs of University accommodation are listed at

http://www.reading.ac.uk/ready-to-study/study/fees-and-funding/fees-and-funding-ug/living-costs.aspx

and you can see rental properties on sites like rightmove.co.uk

Comment: thank you for the information!
I also found the share house information here. I will compare them
https://www.rightmove.co.uk/student-accommodation/find.html?locationIdentifier=REGION%5E1114&insId=1